# Django template datetime.weekday name

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-templates

Is there a way to display the weekday of a datetime object in a template as the actual name of the weekday? Basically I want it to print `Friday` instead of `5`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

See the documentation for the [built-in `date` filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#date).  From there you'll see you need to use:

> l Day of the week, textual, long. 'Friday'

Comment: Thanks! I couldn't find that documentation

Answer (score 12):

For clarity's sake, the template tag format character "l" (lower-case "L") can be used in the Django template like so:

```
{{ object.some_date_field | date:"l" }}
```

Django 1.8.2

Answer (score 4):

You can also use:

```
import datetime
today = datetime.datetime.today()
print(today.strftime('%A'))
```