# how to get date value in django template in format 1-7 day (weeks)

Tags: django, date, templates, filter

Please tell me if there is a way to transfer the day of the week, Monday -1, ... Sunday -7 to the django template. I found nothing among the tags and filters.to display numbers. for example Monday -1, Sunday 7

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32878074/4751726

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible. Just apply a filter to your variable. The filter value is a lower L -> l

In template:

```
    Issued at: {{ invoice.issued_at | date:"l" }}
```

Html is rendered as:
[image]

Source: [Built-in template tags | Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/builtins/#date)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can do it on django template, I recommend you use [Pendulum](https://pypi.org/project/pendulum/) in your view

```
>>> import pendulum

>>> dt = pendulum.parse('2012-09-05T23:26:11.123789')

# These properties specifically return integers
>>> dt.year
2012
>>> dt.month
9
>>> dt.day
5
```